# Ejecting/unmounting random USB flash drive in Raspberry pi / Python

Tags: bash, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian

So I'm trying to get a working code in Python that will eject/unmount all USB flash drives attached to the Pi (Running Raspbian) - so that they can be removed safely. The final code will be run from within the python program.

Additionally, I'd like to eject/unmount the USB flash drive even if it's in use.

I've looked around and can't see how to do this. Thanks.

---

`udisks --detach /media/pi/DOCS/` - 'Blocked device... Resource temporarily available'...

`udisks --detach /media/pi/` - 'Blocked device...Resource temporarily available'...

`udisks --detach /media/` - 'Blocked device...Resource temporarily available'...

`sudo udisks --detach /media/pi/DOCS/` - still blocked...

`sudo umount /path/to/devicename` - command not found...

`eject /media/pi/DOCS/` - Unable to open '/dev/sda'

(DOCS is the name if my USB flash drive. - though I want to eject all USB flash drives - not just my one)

---

So I'm going to ask the user in Python to select their USB flash drive from a list, which is pretty easy (just read in the folder) - so I will have the pathway to the USB. I'm still not sure which code can safely disconnect the USB flash drive - Maybe more research is the answer. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Edit your post with things you have done.

Comment: What does this have to do with tkinter?

Comment: sorry, Nae - nothing really - the button's written in tkinter. I removed the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `udisks --detach` the parameter should be the device, not the mounting point.
For example, if the USB Disk is `/dev/sdb` the command would be `udisks --detach /dev/sdb`

If the command still doesn't work you could try `udiskctl power-off -b <device>` which should also work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - so the pathway that appears on my Pi is /media/pi/DOCS - not /dev/sdb. Any idea what path I should use?

Comment: @DavidW.Beck `/media/pi/DOCS` is the Mount pount, but not the device.
What Output do you get from `mount | grep /media/pi/DOCS`?

Comment: /dev/sda1 on /media/pi/DOCS type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)

Comment: Okay, so your USB Device is found under `/dev/sda`.
So, for ejecting you should use `udisks --detach /dev/sda`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, I'm getting 'one or more partitions are busy on /dev/sda' - 
I think this is the correct command however it's being automated.

Answer (score 2):

so I found the answer:

```
sudo eject /dev/sda1
```

-This disconnects the USB flash drive on a Raspberry Pi.

Thank you very much to everyone who helped!